# Keyboards makes a sound after pressing ctrl and any other key?

Tags: windows-8

This problem happens at start up. My computer acts like the ctl key is always being press. It also makes a beebing sound when pressed. When I hold the crtl key and then press another key. It makes a different sound and the problem goes away. I have noticed this sound alot lately when I either restart or wake after hibernating. Can anybody tell me what the problem could be? I'm using Windows 8.1 pro.

Comment: have you enabled sticky keys? Press SHIFT 5 times and disable it.

Comment: I checked the sticky settings and the only thing turned on is the playing of sound for the toggle keys (The one under the toggle key option).

Comment: I don't know what do on Win8, but does disabling sticky keys, and the option for the sound stop the sound from being made?